# Digital Signature on Canvas with Selenium Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, digital-signature, signature

I'm currently working on automating a web application using Selenium and Java. Our task involves automating a digital signature on a canvas element, but unfortunately, nothing seems to be drawn on the canvas.

I've included my automation script and the relevant HTML code below. Could anyone provide guidance or a solution to this issue?

```
 WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.id("react-sketch-canvas__canvas-background"));

        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action draw = builder.moveToElement(canvas, 50, 50) // Start at position (50, 50)
                            .clickAndHold()
                            .moveByOffset(100, 0) // Draw a line to the right (100 pixels)
                            .moveByOffset(0, 100) // Draw a line downwards (100 pixels)
                            .release()
                            .build();

        draw.perform();
```

HTML code:

```
<g id="react-sketch-canvas__canvas-background-group"><rect id="react-sketch-canvas__canvas-background" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect></g>
<rect id="react-sketch-canvas__canvas-background" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
<g id="react-sketch-canvas__canvas-background-group"><rect id="react-sketch-canvas__canvas-background" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect></g>
```

I tried doing that using Javascript and Actions class but nothing works.